# Should I use throw() when implementing non-throwing swap?

Tags: c++, swap, noexcept

When implementing the non-throwing swap idiom, should I use `throw()`?

```
namespace A
{
   struct B
   {
     void swap( B& other ) throw()
     { /* fancy stuff that doesn't throw */ }
   };

   void swap( B& lhs, B& rhs ) throw()
   { lhs.swap(rhs); }
}

namespace std
{
   template<>
   void swap( A::B& lhs, A::B& rhs ) throw()
   { lhs.swap(rhs); }
}
```

In particular I worry about putting the `throw()` specification on the specialization of `std::swap`.

Bonus question:
Is the answer different when using C++0x's `noexcept` keyword?

Comment: You can simplify those three swap declarations down to one: `struct B { friend void swap(B &a, B &b) { /*...*/ } };`, then simply require users to use swap as `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` which pulls in your swap through ADL (or they can use boost::swap, which already does this).  In particular, this obviates the worry about an exception specification on std::swap, if you decide to use one for your swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03 you can put it there, but if it's true that the fancy stuff doesn't throw, it's basically just documentation. It may or may not affect performance by adding the equivalent of `try / catch(...) { std::unexpected(); }` around calls to the function: it's up to the implementation whether it can do it without affecting performance.

If you're planning to use the `noexcept` *operator* (5.3.7) in C++0x, then suddenly it becomes worth having non-throwing exception specifications, so that the operator gives the "right" answer. I don't really know what the `noexcept` operator is for, but if there's a clever generic use for it, for example algorithms that become more efficient when something is non-throwing, then I guess it's going to become necessary to mark functions as non-throwing, to get whatever the benefit is.

For example:

```
void foo() noexcept;
void bar();

template <void(*FUNC)()>
void generic_thing() {
    if (noexcept(FUNC()) {
        // this won't throw, perhaps we can somehow take advantage of that
        FUNC();
    } else {
        // this might throw
        FUNC();
    }
}
```

Old style exception specifications (*dynamic-exception-specification*) are deprecated in C++0x (and pointless in C++03).

Comment: The `noexcept` operator does not require an expression.  ie `noexcept == noexcept(true)`. see §15.4-1 in the FCD.

Comment: @caspin: the `noexcept` *operator* does. It's a unary operator defined in 5.3.7, and it tests whether an expression *could* throw, without evaluating it. Agreed that the noexcept *keyword*, used in an *exception-specification*, doesn't require an expression. Not sure why I put `(true)` in there.

Comment: does the `noexcept` operator returns a `bool constexpr` ? I would say it's definitely possible and thus it should be possible to use this as a template parameter... Although I do suspect that any compiler worth its salt would eliminate the dead branch and remove the `if` altogether here if the result is computable at compilation time... and why should it not ?

Comment: @Matthieu: the language in the spec is that the result is a constant of type `bool`, so I guess that's the same as a `constexpr`. And I agree, I'd expect the compiler to eliminate one of the branches in each instantiation of my template. I'm not bothered for this example, as long as it executes the presumed-faster non-throwing branch were possible - I was just trying to write a simple example how an algorithm could use operator noexcept. I didn't want to get into using it as a template parameter, especially if it ends up requiring partial specialization on the boolean template parameter...

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea, no. The reason is that the standard knows that at times it's impossible to enforce the `throw()` correctness, which is what `throw()` was brought in for in the first place. In particular, in the case of templates where an exception may or may not be thrown depending on the instantiation it's impossible to check for correctness without the template instantiation. The standard therefore doesn't even require compilers to enforce the exception specifier; in fact, it **forbids** an implementation from rejecting an expression "merely because when executed it throws or might throw an exception that the containing function does not allow" (15.4/11).

If `throw()` has no effect other than documentation then it should be commented out; this way at least it doesn't pose a risk of misleading the human observer.

The case with `noexcept` is wholly different. `noexcept` comes to be for a different reason; that of performance. If **you** can guarantee the compiler no exception is thrown then the compiler allows itself to perform some optimizations. But **you** will have to do the checks yourself. So, if indeed `swap()` doesn't throw (and it shouldn't; that's its raison d'être) then specifying `noexcept` is a good idea.

Comment: "The standard therefore doesn't even require compilers to enforce the exception specifier." - more than this, the standard requires that compilers *don't* enforce exception specifications (15.4/10).

Comment: @SteveJessop correct, thank you for correcting me. It's 15.4/11, by the way.

Comment: @wilhelm: wasn't meant as a correction, just extra information :-). My numbering is from `ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)`, i.e. C++03. As you say, it's 15.4/11 in the C++0x FCD.

Comment: @Steve Ah. I refer to [n1905.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) because that's all I have. :-S

Comment: @wilhelmtell: if you want the FCD, it's free (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf). If you want C++03, you could try searching the internet for the full name of the document. You might find a free download somewhere.

Comment: In the FCD §15.4/12 it says that `throw()` and `noexcept` are functionally equivalent in that they make the function *non-throwing*.  It appears that a non-throwing function that throws just calls `std::terminate`.

Comment: @caspin: 15.4/9: `noexcept` means that `terminate` is called. `throw()` means that `unexpected` is called, although it is astonishingly difficult to write a valid version of `unexpected` that does anything other than log something and call `terminate`.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, no. Exception specifications were a lovely idea, but the reality of them was that they hindered more than helped the majority of code. Nobody uses them and they're deprecated in C++0x. Don't spend time writing exception specifications in modern C++.

Comment: I am aware that exception specifications are a bad idea and deprecated.  I thought `throw()` (the empty specification) was the exception to the rule.  I thought `noexcept` was just an updated version of `throw()` with the ability to turn the `throw()` on and off via a compile time expression.